# MySQL join 2 queries to the same table

Tags: mysql, join

Hi i am try to join the following queries to one table

First Query is

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp as Date, Total
FROM
    food
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
LIMIT 45
```

Second Query is

```
SET @row_number = 45;
SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp as Date, Total
FROM
    food
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
LIMIT 50, 45
```

What i want to achieve is a table like below

```
Batch |  Date  |  Total  |     Batch  |  Date     |  Total
 1      9.00am      10          46      12.30pm       10 
 2      10.00am     10          47      1.00pm        10
 -                            -
 45     12.00pm     10          90      2.00pm        10
```

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want only 45 rows ? Side by side results of the two queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Try joining two subqueries:

```
SET @rn1 = 0;
SET @rn2 = 0;

SELECT
    t1.Batch, t1.Date, t1.Total, t2.Batch, t2.Date, t2.Total
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (@rn1:=@rn1 + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp AS Date, Total
    FROM food
    ORDER BY t_stamp
    LIMIT 45
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        (@rn2:=@rn2 + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp AS Date, Total
    FROM food
    ORDER BY t_stamp
    LIMIT 50, 45
) t2
    ON t1.Batch = t2.Batch
ORDER BY
    t1.Date;
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants this. He wants to leave 5 rows at position 45

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Given that you yourself are confused about the requirements, your comment above does not really belong there.  At least not yet.

Comment: I am confused about another requirements, that is, the display output shows the result of two select queries side by side. Regarding skipping 5 rows at position 45, I am clear about that. If you look at the second query, its start position is from 50 :-)

Comment: Double looked at your query; you are definitely getting right rows, but I think row numbering will be off. You may need to re-determine row numbering in outer select. Just a suggestion :-)

Comment: No, you're right.  I updated my answer to do a join.  I think it might work, because we are materializing the actual row numbers before we join using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UNION ALL for merging two dataset

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @row_number1 = 45;

select * from
(SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp as Date, Total
FROM
    food
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
LIMIT 45
)A
union all

select * from
(
SELECT 
    (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) AS Batch, t_stamp as Date, Total
FROM
    food
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
LIMIT 50, 45
)
B
```